# Is it possible to calculate how fast something will roll down a hill?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

If I have a wheel, I know it's mass and diameter and the slope of a hill. Can I calculate the time it will take to get to the bottom of the hill? I am doing a project for my science fair and I sent 5 wheels down a hill. I thought the biggest wheel would go fastest but it didn't. I don't know why. The middle wheel wheel went the fastest. It was right in the middle of the weight and diameter. The smallest and lightest wheel went the same speed and the heaviest and biggest wheel.

I know the diameter and masses of the wheels. The length of the hill and the degrees of the slope. Is there a formula that can tell me how fast it should go? I did not push it, I let all the wheels roll just by letting go of them so there wasn't any force.

If anyone could help me understand this my Mom will try to explain what you tell me.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate it, but some assumptions would have to be made. Namely the wheel does not slip on the surface, air friction can be neglected and the wheel/surface does not deform big inelastic deformations (which would also dissipate energy).

The result depends on de [(mass) moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia):

[image]

Comment: Hi, no matter how many times I roll the wheels down the hill, I get different results each time. It's an 8ft slide and they are skateboard wheels with a hole in the middle. they are the same material. I thought the bigger wheel would win more often but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to find the individual moment of inertias of the wheels. If they are hollow cylindrical shells with negligible thickness then you can take their moment of inertia about the rotational axis as $mR^2$ where $m$ is the mass of the wheel and $R$ is the radius.

[image]

Now, as fibonatic mentioned, you will have to assume that the wheel does not slip and there is no air drag. Let $\omega$ be the angular velocity at an instant and $v$ be the linear velocity. Hence, $v=\omega R$. Consider the diagram below,

[image]

Linear acceleration, $a=\alpha R$

Torque on the wheel will be $$\tau =I\alpha =f_sR$$

So, $$f_s=\frac{I\alpha}{R}=\frac{Ia}{R^2}$$

Also, we can see that $$mgSin\theta - f_s=ma$$

Solve the above equations to get $a$ for each of the wheels.

Comment: $a!=g\sin\theta$

Comment: use \sin­­­­­­­

Comment: @Awesome what do you mean?

Comment: You wrote a= g sin theta which contradicts your last equation

Comment: @Awesome yeah you are right, thanks for pointing it out, I'll edit it right away.

Comment: Hi, no matter how many times I roll the wheels down the hill, I get different results each time. It's an 8ft slide and they are skateboard wheels with a hole in the middle. they are the same material. I thought the bigger wheel would win more often but it doesn't.

Comment: The largest wheel is 63mm diameter and weighs 4 ounces. The smallest is 48mm and weighs 2 ounces. Going down a 10 foot ramp with no wind and no pushing, a 90 degree angle. the small one finishes at 7.8 seconds and the large one at 8.7.

Comment: I'm really confused because I thought it was going to be really easy and the results would be the same each time.

Comment: @user44128- there are too many things which can go wrong while doing this. The wheel has to be sturdy first of all, second when you release it, it should go in a straight line and should not bounce at all. Also, is the shape of the wheel the same as the picture I out up?

Comment: Yup. round wheel with a small hole in the middle. they are new skateboard wheels. it didn't bounce and it did go striaght. we made a track to it wouldn't go off to the side too much. all of the wheels were sent down the same track and we swept it clean each time. We even videotaped it and all the wheels came across so close to each other. it was a different wheel each time but the smallest wheel won the most

Comment: I am going to finish it today and the teach said my conclusion doesn't have to be right. She said I could tell what I would do differently next time